# Getting SparseBooleanArray.size() always 0 when getting checked items from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am using checkboxes in the listview and want to get the selected items in the ListView.The problem is that the SparseBooleanArray.size() always remains 0 even when the checkboxes are checked in the listView.I have searched a lot but the problem remains the same.This is the code i am using:

```
checked = lvShowContacts.getCheckedItemPositions();
if(checked != null)
{
    for (int i=0; i<checked.size(); i++) {
        if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
            String item = lvShowContacts.getAdapter().getItem(
                    checked.keyAt(i)).toString();
            Log.v("Message",item + " was selected");
        }
    }
    Log.v("Message","checked.size() is "+ checked.size());
    //  else
    //the item is not checked, do something else
}
```

Here i am always getting `checked.size()` as `0`.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use `lvShowContacts.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`?

Comment: What row layout are you using? Does it implement Checkable?

Answer (score 1):

Some tips on using SparseBooleanArray:

Let sba be a SparseBooleanArray object.

`sba.size()` returns the total number of items in the Array.
Now the array contains a mapping of an Integer value to position, in this case the position of the selected listview items are mapped to the respective boolean status.
Use `sba.keyAt(i)` to find the integer value of the boolean Array and then use `sba.get(sba.keyAt(i))` to find the respective boolean value that is mapped to the integer key.

You can loop through the Array like this:

```
SparseBooleanArray sba= getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
    for(int i=0;i<sba.size();i++){
        Log.i("SparseBoolaeanArray","Element "+sba.keyAt(i)+":status::"+sba.get(sba.keyAt(i)));
```

Comment: Thats a clean explanation. Thanks, it fixed one bug for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop on the selected rows

```
int len = listView.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 if (checked.get(i)) {    
  /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
 }
```

You will find this answer in this thread:[How to get Selected items from Multi Select List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590856/how-to-get-selected-items-from-multi-select-list-view#answer-4590897)

Answer (score 0):

For me, checked.size() always returns 0 and the values appear to reach 12 at first but with the correct key/value pairs. So I just use the getCount of the ListView to get the limit of the iteration and finish when I encounter an IndexOutOfBoudsException. Ugly as hell but so far it works.

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = this.list.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.list.getCount(); i++){
                    if (checked.valueAt(i)){                        
                        Object r = this.list.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));
                        ids.add(r.getId());                 
                    }               
                }
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the sparsebooleanarray by converting it toString and then splitting it at the ",". But let me tell you, this is not a very trustworthy approach, from what i have known so far, at first it gets only the checked items, it stores:`{0=true, 1=true, 2=true}` but suppose you saved its state somehow (using shared pref,etc) and then uncheck the checked item, it then returns,
`{0=true, 1=true, 2=false},ie, this time the size of the array will be 3 even when true state is only carried by 2.`

So be careful while relying on size of sparsebooleanarray even when it returns a count.