# Add Two radio button in listview like yes or no buttons in each row of list

Tags: android, json, listview

I created a custom layout with one textview and two radio button.Textview fetches data form json url and show names in list format with two radio button in each row.but radio buttons are not actually connected.They show in each row but are not activated.so How to set these radio buttons with textview data so that after click on submit button that is not in image,can upload string like "yes" or "no" according to radio button check in json url.

there is an url https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkrLE.png

Comment: try with this way Link are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278839/custom-listactivity-with-checkbox-gets-an-error/28279443#28279443

Comment: you can add multiple items over there can be your choice..

Comment: implement custom adopter for your listview and use radiogroup