# how to made each list clickable to redirect on it's url parsed through json

Tags: android, json, eclipse

*I parsed a json object using an API and retrieve its data containing ID,Title, Url, Promotion etc now i am displaying it's Title and Promotion in listview and i want to make that list clickable to redirect on it's same url which i am getting from JSON object every list contains different urls.
So how can i do it?*

```
  for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString(ID);
                Log.e(id, "Json ID inside of it");
                String title = c.getString(TITLE);
                Log.e(title, "Json ID inside of it");
                String url = c.getString(URL);

                Log.e(url, "Json ID inside of it");
                String offer = c.getString(OFFER);
                String enddate =c.getString(ENDDATE);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                map.put(ID, id);
                map.put(TITLE, title);
                map.put(URL, url);
                map.put(OFFER, offer);
                map.put(ENDDATE, enddate);
                jsonlist.add(map);
                Log.e(ID, "check if id ave xsmething");
                Log.e(id, "check if id ave xsmething");
                Log.e(TITLE, "check if id ave xsmething");
                Log.e(title, "check if id ave xsmething");
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

*My XML file is*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: don't have any idea what to try ?

Comment: try with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278839/custom-listactivity-with-checkbox-gets-an-error/28279443#28279443

Comment: it's not what i'm asking!

Comment: In your adapter class for filling the listview, add an OnClickListener on the view, and open the URL. Use an Intent for opening the URL.