# Get all checked items from ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-xml

If I have a `ListView` with the layout below where each item has a checkbox, how can I get all the checked items in the `onClick()` method when I click the `Button`?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="submitList"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `onClick()` method:

```
public void submitList(View view) {
    //
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: See following tut [Android - Get Selected Items from ListView with CheckBox](http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/android-listview/checkbox-in-listview--event-handling--1)

Answer (score 1):

You can check listview items one by one:

```
for ( int i=0; i < listview.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
listview.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SparseBooleanArray` to get the checked items if you are using the `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`.
Here is the reference of StackoverFlow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590856/how-to-get-selected-items-from-multi-select-list-view).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make one arraylist with size of your listview adapter. After that when you check any of your list item add that item in your array list.

```
public ArrayList<String> getCheckedName()
    {
        return array_list;
    }
```

Write this function in your adapter class. And when you want your checked data call

```
ArrayList<String> sName=adapter.getCheckedName();
```

Use this sName in your onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = listview.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = listview.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (checked.get(i))
        String item = yourArrayList.get(i);
}
```