# Onclick of ListView Item, check the checkox?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a listview that is built from textviews with the built in Resource Layout **simple_list_item_multiple_choice**.
syntax like this :

*ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, internet);*

If the user clicks an item list, the checkbox of selected item has to be checked.

I know to implement ***OnItemClickListner***, But after it what should I do to check the selected item.

Comment: You could use adapter.getItem(position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu can try this ,referred from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590897/5193608.

SparseBooleanArray.get returns a boolean, but I believe you need to check it for each position in your list, e.g.

```
int len = listView.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 if (checked.get(i)) {
  String item = cont_list.get(i);
  /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
 }
```